# Can we delete the dplyr tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

Currently we have 3 questions which are tagged with the ["dplyr" tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dplyr). All three of them have zero votes. In my opinion questions related to this tag and this R library are about data wrangling in R. Therefore I think they are off-topic as they are primarily about coding and not about statistics or data visualisation itself. Can we delete the "dplyr" tag?

Comment: Related discussion: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/the-pandas-tag#comment12761_4678

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see why not. You make good points.

Answer (score 10):

The two questions by tomclark seem to be on topic -- "*What is the best way to test if the number of Males in group 1 is significantly greater than group 2, which is 0?*" is *clearly* a statistical question (I am astonished to think that anyone would maintain that's off topic here. In need of clarification, perhaps, but definitely within our scope).

Unfortunately they're duplicates of each other, so one should be deleted or the two should be merged. Unfortunately, one has been extensively edited -- so it has more information -- while the other has the longer answers; I'll have to think about how to tidy that up.

While I definitely disagree with deleting both of those, the other one does look off topic and should be closed (which I just did).

Either way, the dplyr tag doesn't seem to be needed; it's not relevant to the statistical question being asked.  (whuber's suggestion of keeping the tag but warning that a question using it may be off topic is an interesting proposal, and defnitely worth considering)

Comment: What do you think of *keeping* such tags and instead setting their wiki excerpts to warn that the question might be off-topic?

Comment: @whuber How many tag wikis have you read? I'd bet that most of the people didn't ever read *any* tag wiki.

Comment: We needn't close / delete the *questions* necessarily. If we just remove the tag, it will disappear after 24 hours.

Comment: @Tim I refer to the *excerpt* that pops up when you hover your mouse over the tag.  I won't suppose that the way in which I interact with the site generalizes to all users, so whether I see or read the excerpts is irrelevant.  But I don't want to abandon a potentially useful mechanism or not employ it just because some people might not notice it.

Comment: @whuber that's a good thought; there's clearly an argument for that.

Comment: Re duplicated posts: I copied edits from the later version into the earlier one and voted to close the later one as a duplicate. In fact, as it's 100% identical duplicate and does not contain useful or upvoted answers/comments I think it can be deleted altogether. I downvoted so that if closed, it eventually gets automatically deleted